# UITableView cells doesn't fit UITableView height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I download Json data and then I populate my custom UITableView, the problem is that even if I calculate the height of the tableview based on the amount of elements I download the cells doesn't fit the whole height of the tableview, So my final situation is a tableview with n elements that has height of n*100 but the cells just fits a part of it.
This is the code I used to calculate the height:

```
//callback that contains the items I download
-(void)productsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{

    _productsDetails = items;

    CGFloat height = 100;
    height *= items.count;

    CGRect tableFrame = _customTableView.frame;
    tableFrame.size.height = height;
    _customTableView.frame = tableFrame;

    [_customTableView reloadData];

}
```

I also tried:

```
_customTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
_customTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

But with no results.. How can I tell the cells to fit the height of the cell?

Comment: Do you mean that there are empty cells in the table view with the downloaded data at the top?

Comment: You shouldn't set the tableView frame. That's causing your problem.

Comment: no I mean that the cells doesn't fit the whole content of the table but stops at a certain height

Comment: Are you using auto-layout? Can your table size requirement be larger than the screen (or is the table inside another scroll view)?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a scrollable table view, you have to use the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method to specify the size (height) or your cell, not just change the frame of your table view.

Example:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //TODO: Calculate cell height
    return 60.0f;
}
```

---

To have all the cells visible on one screen, the total height of the table view cells has to be equal to the height of the table view, thus the height of one table view cell should be:

```
CGFloat cellHeight = CGRectGetHeight(tableView.frame) / numberOfCells;
```

However, I really don't understand why you would want to do this. The whole reason of a table view is to have a fixed height for cells and scroll (Like the Settings app does it).

Comment: yeah I already did that, the problem is that the TableView has the correct height (for example 10 items, height = 1000) but the cells stops at 500 and then I have to scroll in order to see them

Comment: In addition, this would interfere with an implementation of dynamic type. It would look really funky to have so much text crammed into such a small cell or vice versa. As @LordZsolt stated, the point of a table view is to scroll content.